# What is the meaning of the rules for Java assembly instruction instanceof?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

When drilling down to the operator `instanceof` on the Java bytecode assembly instruction level, it corresponds to a Java assembly instruction [`instanceof`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.instanceof). But I read the rules used to

> determine whether an objectref that is not null is an instance of the resolved type:

The second rule told:

> If S is an interface type, then:
>
> - If T is a class type, then T must be Object.
> - If T is an interface type, then T must be the same interface as S or a superinterface of S.

This made me confused. Does "S is an interface type" mean the reference type of S is an interface type? if so the first rule "If T is a class type, then T must a Object" can not hold true. For instance,

```
CharSequence charSequence = new StringBuilder("test");
System.out.println(charSequence instanceof StringBuilder);
System.out.println(charSequence instanceof String);
```

the second line in the code above would print true, whereas the third line above would print false. So I doubt my understanding is probably wrong, anyone can help to explain the meaning of the rule above?

Comment: 'S is the class of the object referred to by *objectref*': in this case, `StringBuilder`. The third line printing `false` is correct.

Comment: @EJP But don't you think the first rule I mentioned is different from what should be printed from the code I gave? String is Object, isn't it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right to be confused, as the way these rules have been written, *are* confusing.

For an *objectref*, it is *impossible* to have an interface type, as each instantiated object has an actual, non-abstract type, perhaps implementing an interface. This even applies to the instances generated for lambda expressions, which have an unspecified (anonymous) type implementing the functional interface.

So at the first glance, it appears that this part of these rules make no sense. But consider the full text:

> The following rules are used to determine whether an *objectref* that is not `null` is an instance of the resolved type: If `S` is the class of the object referred to by *objectref* and `T` is the resolved class, array, or interface type, *instanceof* determines whether *objectref* is an instance of `T` as follows:
>
> - If `S` is an ordinary (nonarray) class, then:
>
>   - If `T` is a class type, then `S` must be the same class as `T`, or `S` must be a subclass of T;
>   - If `T` is an interface type, then `S` must implement interface `T`.
> - If `S` is an interface type, then:
>
>   - If `T` is a class type, then `T` must be Object.
>   - If `T` is an interface type, then `T` must be the same interface as `S` or a superinterface of `S`.
> - If `S` is a class representing the array type `SC[]`, that is, an array of components of type `SC`, then:
>
>   - If `T` is a class type, then `T` must be Object.
>   - If `T` is an interface type, then `T` must be one of the interfaces implemented by arrays (JLS §4.10.3).
>   - If `T` is an array type `TC[]`, that is, an array of components of type `TC`, then one of the following must be true:
>
>     - `TC` and `SC` are the same primitive type.
>     - `TC` and `SC` are reference types, and type `SC` can be cast to `TC` by these run-time rules.

Since it is impossible for the actual object referenced by *objectref* to have an interface type, only the other two bullets apply; its type is either, an “ordinary (nonarray) class” or an array type. In the latter case, the last sentence is the interesting one, as it refers to the cited rules as a whole, to be applied to the component types of `T` and `S` if both are arrays of a reference type. And the component type may be an interface type.

So you can test these rules using an actual array instance of an interface type, checking against other array types:

```
Object o = new Collection[0]; // SC is Collection
System.out.println(o instanceof Object[]); // TC is class type Object -> true
System.out.println(o instanceof String[]); // TC is class type other than Object -> false
System.out.println(o instanceof Collection[]); // TC == SC -> true
System.out.println(o instanceof Iterable[]); // TC is super interface of SC -> true
System.out.println(o instanceof List[]); // TC is not super interface SC -> false
```

It think, it would be less confusing, if the interface case was described within the array special case, where it may apply. On the other hand, these three cases follow the general formal assignment rules, so they are easier to recognize in this form.

Comment: so this would work only because arrays are covariant right? I can't think of a single place where I have seen an isntanceOf against an array though

Comment: @Eugene: this is one of the rules which *make* arrays covariant.